# What pronunciation is '骑‘ in 千里走单骑’的‘骑’是什么的骑？qi 或者 ji?

Tags: meaning

Web page wants me to write some English.
“千里走单骑” 的“骑”是什么意思？

“几天时间里，单骑千里，过五关斩六将，威风八面，气概冲霄。”

关羽厉害的！

还有：‘威风八面 = 威风凛凛’了吗？

Comment: tw = ji, dl = qi? maybe.

Comment: I have never heard of the phrase 千里走單騎 being pronounced with **qí**..

Comment: It is very strange that people are uncertain about the pronunciation. I cannot imagine a similar situation in English. Asking around, first I was told ji, then qi then 'not sure'.

Comment: @Pedroski Chinese is still being *standardized*. You should ask people how to read 凿, the reading that was taught 20 years ago is not what is considered *standard* nowadays.

Comment: It reads `jì` in this case before, but unique `qí` currently.

Answer (score 2):

《[普通话异读词审音表](http://faculty.arts.ubc.ca/tli/guideline/shenyinbiao.pdf)》规定，“骑”在现代汉语中“统读”qí。

According to the 《[The Authorized Table of Mandarin Words with Variant Pronunciations](http://faculty.arts.ubc.ca/tli/guideline/shenyinbiao.pdf)》，the word “骑”  is always pronounced with qí in modern Chinese.

A famous and popular Chinese professor, 易中天 (Zhongtian Yi), who is famous for his lectures of 三国演义, pronounced "骑" in "千里走单骑" as qí. You may also search "千里走单骑" on youtube, and you may find that in many videos, it is pronounced as qí. For example, 0:38 in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzLT9blEYdc

Comment: 三国演义was written a long time ago. I'm reading a simplified version, not the original, but there may be throw backs.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But a famous and popular Chinese professor, 易中天 (Zhongtian Yi), who is famous for his lectures of 三国演义, pronounced "骑" in "千里走单骑" as qí. You can search "千里走单骑" on youtube, and you will find that many of the videos pronounced "骑" as qí.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pronunciation `jì`, means `one man with one horse`, I have been taught like this since middle school. Then I (and I have heard **some** other people) speak `jì` when 骑 is used as noun, like 单骑闯关, 一骑红尘妃子笑, 车骑将军, 坐骑...

Most people always speak `qi`, I understood that they just don't know the right pronunciation.

**But** I just searched dictionary before post this answer, the results surprises me..., I have to search more information.

According to the 《现代汉语词典》, `ji` is deprecated by a department officially and mannualy in 1985.

So now, I know that according to their direction I should speak `qi` always.

BTW, I hadn't been born by 1985. And I will continue to speak `ji`, otherwise I would be disgusted.

Answer (score 1):

In modern mandarin, we don't differentiate qi and ji for 骑 and it's pronounced as qi2 most of time. Well, ancient does differentiate the pronunciation for ji4 and qi.

For example,

> 一骑红尘妃子笑，无人知是荔枝来。

It's pronounced as ji4.

I guess in the areas where traditional characters are still in use, they would pronounce it as ji4. Well, in mainland, we pronounce it as qi2 in practice. Some may argue that the correct pronunciation is ji4, but the language is all about the conventions, so it seems qi2 becomes more common nowadays.

I suggest when you use it in an ancient context, pronounce it as ji4, and qi2 in a casual or colloquial conversation.

Answer (score 0):

> [千里走单骑](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%8D%83%E9%87%8C%E8%B5%B0%E5%8D%95%E9%AA%91/15797)是中国古典小说《三国演义》中的故事情节之一
>
> 'Ride a thousand miles alone' is one of the storylines in the classic Chinese novel The Romance of the Three Kingdoms.

千里 (thousand miles) is a figurative term for "vast distance"

走 in this context means "travel"

单 means "single"

骑 means "horse"

单骑 mostly mean 'a lone horseman' (Since it is a noun, It should read as /ji4/ ;  (as a verb it read /qi2/)

In this context, it refers to "关羽 (Guan Yu) traveled on 单骑 (a single horse)" or " "关羽 (Guan Yu) traveled as a 单骑 (lone horseman)".  骑 is a noun in either case.

In day to day speech, many people read 骑 as /qi2/ regardless of it is noun or verb

> 千里走单骑 literally means "For a thousand, travel on a single horse"

~

> *还有：‘威风八面 = 威风凛凛’了吗？*

When someone achieved fearsome feat, it can be described as "威风八面"(shock and awe everyone) ; "威风凛凛" describes "one with fearsome aurora" mostly about appearance and feel